# How to find all (complete) sublinks from a web page using lxml in Python

Tags: python, html, url, web-scraping, lxml

The following code takes a URL and returns a list of links to pages that are contained on the original url page.

```
import urllib
import lxml.html

def getSubLinks(url):
sublinks = []
connection = urllib.urlopen(url)
dom = lxml.html.fromstring(connection.read())
for link in dom.xpath('//a/@href'):
    sublinks.append(link)
return sublinks
```

This seems to work, except for, for pages on the same domain it strips the domain from the URL and this is not what I want. I want to get the full unaltered link back. For example, using this on the webpage:

"http://www.nufc.com"

returns the list (and much more):

```
['http://www.altoonativetravel.com/', 'index.htm',    '2015-16html/fixtures.html', .....
```

However as you can see the preceding "http://www.nufc.com" has been stripped from '2015-16html/fixtures.html' and others whereas I do not want this to happen, I want 'http://www.nufc.com/2015-16html/fixtures.html'. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following:

```
import urllib
import lxml.html

def getSubLinks(url):
    sublinks = []
    connection = urllib.urlopen(url)
    dom = lxml.html.fromstring(connection.read())
    for link in dom.xpath('//a/@href'):
        if not link.startswith('http'):
            sublinks.append(url+link)
        else:
            sublinks.append(link)
    return sublinks
```

When calling your function, use `getSubLinks('http://www.nufc.com/')` (note the `/` at the end of the URL).

This loops over each of the `href` attributes of the `a` tags on the page. For each link, if the link doesn't start with `"http"`, it will append `url+link`, ie `"http://www.nufc.com/" + link`. This will generate your desired results set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can we be sure that all non-http starting links can simply be altered like this. What about items such as  'mailto:example@example.com'? It doesn't make sense to append the URL to the front of this. Also, what if a link only starts with 'www'? Then we will obtain 'http://www.nufc.com/www. ...'.

Comment: Fair enough, but you get the idea! You just need to be creative and cover all of your desired use cases with extra conditions. You could alter to `if not link.startswith('http') and not link.startswith('www') and not '@' in link:`

Comment: That is possible, but my main concern is how many of these cases are there? Is there a way to prevent lxml from stripping these links in the first place?

Comment: It isn't the fault of `lxml`. `lxml` is simply reading/parsing the HTML as it is displayed. It is up to us to then decipher the absolute and relative links. I think we have covered all the use cases - a simple Google should show any more use cases. Alternatively, you can ping a `request` to each of the generated links and view the status code (not recommending you do this in large quantities...!)

Comment: Inspecting the html shows that this is not the original format of the links, so lxml must be changing it.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: just when I go to the website and inspect a link, such as 'match report is online here'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99836/discussion-between-lambo477-and-j-s).